# A Markov Chain - Let X ~ the heads of M coins

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, discrete-time

> A Markov chain is defined as follows. There are $M$ coins $(M ∈ \mathbb N)$, each showing Heads or Tails. At each step, a coin is selected uniformly at random and flipped. The state of the system is the number of Heads.
>
> > (a) Determine the transition matrix of the Markov chain.
> >
> > (b) Using any method, determine the stationary distribution (your solution should prove that the distribution you find is in fact the stationary distribution).
> >
> > (c) Suppose $M = 20$ and the initial state is $X_0 = 10$. How long, on average, will it take until the next time the state is $10$?

**My question**

I am not sure for (b), how to prove its time reversibility.

---

**My attempt so far**

(a) $P_{i,i+1} = \frac{M-i}{2M}$, $P_{i,i-1} = \frac{i}{2M}$, $P_{i,i} = \frac{1}{2}$

(b) Using the property of time reversible Markov chain (*without proving*), I could get $\pi_0 = 2^{-M}, \pi_i = {M \choose i}2^{-M}$.

(c) I'm guessing that the average time to return to state $10$ is $\frac{1}{\pi_{10}}$. Still, I need to prove the time reversibility to be able to use it.

Comment: The infamous Ehrenfest Urn, only the name is missing

Comment: As soon as you get a solution for $\pi_i P_{i,i+1}=\pi_{i+1} P_{i+1,i}$, you KNOW $P$ is reversible with respect to $\pi$ (a definition !) and you get for free that $\pi$ a stationary measure for $P$ (a one line general fact : $\sum_i \pi_i P(i,j) =  \sum_i \pi_j P(j,i)=\pi_j$). So that (b) is not an issue. Also, the result you mention in (c) does not require reversibility, only irreducibility (again this is plain in your case).

Comment: So for (c), is the answer $(\frac{20!}{10!10!}2^{-20})^{-1}$?

Comment: Is it true that for all irreducible Markov chains are time reversible?

Comment: It is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove (b) is correct you want to show that the probbabilities remain the same after one step, so here that $\forall i$ $$P_{i-1,i}\pi_{i-1}+P_{i,i}\pi_{i}+P_{i+1,i}\pi_{i+1} =\pi_{i}$$ i.e. $$\frac{M-(i-1)}{2M}{M \choose i-1}2^{-M} + \frac12 {M \choose i}2^{-M} +\frac{i+1}{2M}{M \choose i+1}2^{-M} = {M \choose i}2^{-M}$$ remembering that ${M \choose -1}= {M \choose M+1}=0$

Comment: What is the related formula or theorem related to $\frac{M-(i-1)}{2M}{M \choose i-1}2^{-M} + \frac12 {M \choose i}2^{-M} +\frac{i+1}{2M}{M \choose i+1}2^{-M} = {M \choose i}2^{-M}$? I could prove it by hand but it took me nasty and long calculation to do it. Is there any easier way to prove that than expanding everything?

Comment: @soobster The left hand side is $\frac12 2^{-M}\left( {M-1 \choose i-1} + {M \choose i} + {M-1 \choose i}\right)$ and, since ${M-1 \choose i-1} +  {M-1 \choose i}={M \choose i}$ (think Pascal's triangle), this is equal to $2^{-M} {M \choose i}$ i.e. the right hand side

Answer (score 1):

- We can represent this situation as a Markov chain with $M+1$ states, corresponding to the possible number $k\in \{0,\ldots,M\}$ of heads-up coins.
- Given the state with $k$ heads-up coins, a transition occurs by choosing one of the coins and flipping it. We can consider two cases: half the time, the coin we pick lands same-side-up; hence we transition into the same state again. The other half of the time, the coin lands opposite-side-up, and we either gain or lose a head.

  Hence the transition probability is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of transitioning to the same state again, a $\frac{k}{2M}$ chance of picking (and toggling) a heads-up coin $k\mapsto (k-1)$, and a $\frac{M-k}{2M}$ chance of picking (and toggling) a tails-up coin $k\mapsto (k+1)$. Note that the probabilities sum to 1, and that these formulas work even for the extreme cases of $k=0$ or $k=M$.
- A steady-state probability distribution is a distribution over all states $k\in\{0,\ldots,M\}$ which remains the same after a single transition step is applied.

  Denoting the probability of each state by $p_0 \ldots p_M$, the transition probabilities give us certain equations that must hold. For example, if the probability on state $0$ is the same before and after transitioning, then $$p_0 = \frac{1}{2} p_0 + \frac{1}{2M}p_1$$

  And similarly for the other states. We also have the law of total probability $\sum_i p_i = 1$. These constraints are enough to uniquely determine the stationary distribution for this ergodic system; you can use a matrix representation to make the calculation smoother.
- There is a theorem which states that if a finite Markov chain has a stationary distribution, then the expected time of return to state $x$ is, as you say, $1/p_x$.

Comment: Wouldn't $p_0$ be $ \frac{1}{2} p_0 + \frac{1}{2M}p_1$ instead?

Comment: Thanks, good catch.